# Javascript - If e Loop

Tags: javascript, array, loop, if

Estou tentando responder uma questão dentro de uma plataforma, e não estou conseguindo ajustar o código conforme o algoritmo deseja. Estou recebendo os seguintes erros : 1- Deve ter um if validando o contador i/ 2- Deve imprimir a mensagem "O morador Fulano de Tal pode usar o elevador". Alguma dica?

Questão :

No fim de semana o elevador do nosso prédio quebrou, restringindo muito o fluxo de pessoas. Considerando isso, apenas os moradores dos apartamentos com número par poderão usar o elevador. Escreva um código que, com base na variável “moradores” nos informe quais moradores poderão utilizar o elevador. O número do apartamento é a sua posição no array, e o nome do morador é o valor.

Imprima no console a lista a seguinte frase: 'O morador ' + nome do morador + ' pode usar o elevador'

// MEU CÓDIGO :

```
var moradores = [
    "Fulano de Tal",
    "Beltrano da Cia",
    "Viajante do Tempo",
    "Morador da Lua",
    "Marciano Azul",
    "Et da Eslováquia",
    "Jedi do Lado Cinza da Força",
    "Baby Yoda Amarelo"
]

for ( var i = 0; i < moradores.length; i++){
    if( moradores[i] % 2 || moradores[i] == 0){
        var nomes = moradores[i]
    }
    
}
    console.log("O morador " + nomes + " pode usar o elevador")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fulano de tal é o morador do apartamento 1, o morador par começa com Beltrano da Cia. Não existe, apartamento 0, portanto é como segue

```js
var moradores = [
    "Fulano de Tal",
    "Beltrano da Cia",
    "Viajante do Tempo",
    "Morador da Lua",
    "Marciano Azul",
    "Et da Eslováquia",
    "Jedi do Lado Cinza da Força",
    "Baby Yoda Amarelo"
]

var nome = '';

for ( var i = 0; i < moradores.length; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
       // ##### Vai de escada ou fica no apartamento :-)
    }else{
        nome = moradores[i]
        console.log("O morador " + nome + " pode usar o elevador")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você quer achar o morador de NÚMERO par, tem que fazer os testes com o contador 'i', o que você tá testando com os teus *ifs* são os nomes, o que não te ajuda a resolver o problema. Outro problema, você tá criando a variável nomes dentro do loop, sobescrevendo ela a cada iteração, e imprimindo depois de tudo isso, dessa maneira, apenas o último morador salvo na variável vai ser impresso, ao invés de todos os qualificados.

Sugiro mudar o código para algo do tipo:

```
var moradores = [
    "Fulano de Tal",
    "Beltrano da Cia",
    "Viajante do Tempo",
    "Morador da Lua",
    "Marciano Azul",
    "Et da Eslováquia",
    "Jedi do Lado Cinza da Força",
    "Baby Yoda Amarelo"
]

var nome = '';

for ( var i = 0; i < moradores.length; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0 || i == 0){
        nome = moradores[i]
        console.log("O morador " + nome + " pode usar o elevador")
    }
    
}
```

Qualquer dúvida em relação ao código, pode perguntar!

Comment: Editei pra ajeitar um erro que tinha cometido

Comment: Agradeço a explicação e a sugestão, realmente modifiquei o codigo e no terminal está imprimindo corretamente, porém o algoritmo da plataforma no qual estou usando ainda indica um erro : Deve ter um if validando o contador i . @placementw

Comment: @placementw Tbm criou uma variável em escopo global sem necessidade alguma!

Comment: fulano de tal é o morador do apartamento 1, o morador par começa com Beltrano da Cia.  Não existe, apartamento 0

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Obrigado, era realmente isso o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez queira considerar utilizar `filter`, assim será criado um novo array somente com os resultados que se enquadram na sua condição!

```js
var moradores = [
    "Fulano de Tal",
    "Beltrano da Cia",
    "Viajante do Tempo",
    "Morador da Lua",
    "Marciano Azul",
    "Et da Eslováquia",
    "Jedi do Lado Cinza da Força",
    "Baby Yoda Amarelo"
];

let moradoresPermitidos = moradores.filter((a, i) => i % 2 === 1);
for (const nome of moradoresPermitidos) {
    console.log(`O morador ${nome} pode usar o elevador`)
}
```

Comment: Agradeço a sugestão, porém o algoritmo não iria aceitar a resolução.

Answer (score -1):

Agora em 2022, eu estou usando essa mesma plataforma e tive exatamente o mesmo aviso que você disse: "Deve ter um if validando o contador i".
Vou deixar a solução registrada aqui, caso mais alguém esteja com a mesma dúvida.

```
var moradores = [
    "Fulano de Tal",
    "Beltrano da Cia",
    "Viajante do Tempo",
    "Morador da Lua",
    "Marciano Azul",
    "Et da Eslováquia",
    "Jedi do Lado Cinza da Força",
    "Baby Yoda Amarelo"
]

for (let i=0; i < moradores.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        console.log("O morador " + moradores[i] + " pode usar o elevador")
    }
}
```